# Selfwritten plugins fail to load on server startup, due to "dependency-circulations"

Tags: minecraft, circular-dependency, spigot

I have two self-written plugins. NovEcon2 and RealBanks2.

NovEcon2 is my economy-plugin, which depends on `Vault` and `RealBanks2` as softdepend.
RealBanks2 is my banking-plugin, which also depends on `Vault`.

Source-code is available here (important, stay in branch `kotlin-rewrite`):

- NovEcon2: https://codeberg.org/Noveria/NovEcon2/src/branch/kotlin-rewrite
- RealBanks2: https://codeberg.org/Noveria/RealBanks2/src/branch/kotlin-rewrite

I have implemented an [api](https://codeberg.org/Noveria/RealBanks2/src/branch/kotlin-rewrite/src/main/kotlin/me/linuxsquare/realbanks2/api/PluginAPI.kt) inside RealBanks2, to access some functions inside [NovEcon2](https://codeberg.org/Noveria/NovEcon2/src/branch/kotlin-rewrite/src/main/kotlin/me/linuxsquare/novecon2/NovEcon2.kt#L115).

The api can be enabled in NovEcon2, via a [configlet-bool](https://codeberg.org/Noveria/NovEcon2/src/branch/kotlin-rewrite/src/main/resources/config.yml#L19) set to `true`
However, since both plugins depend on `Vault`, loading them while the configlet-bool set to `true` is impossible as of now.

Since RealBanks2 requires an economy-plugin to be loaded and NovEcon2 requires RealBanks2 to be loaded, none of them are getting loaded.
That ends in NovEcon2 failing to load, because RealBanks2 isn't loaded and RealBanks2 failing to load, because there is no economy-plugin hooked into vault, such as NovEcon2.

Some other people referred that as a "dependency-circulation".
This is how it looks like in the console, when the server is booting up:

```
[18:31:35 INFO]: [Vault] Enabling Vault v1.7.3-b131
[18:31:35 INFO]: [Vault] [Permission] SuperPermissions loaded as backup permission system.
[18:31:35 INFO]: [Vault] Enabled Version 1.7.3-b131
[18:31:35 INFO]: [NovEcon2] Enabling NovEcon2 v1.0.0
[18:31:35 ERROR]: [NovEcon2] - Disabled due to no RealBanks dependency found!
[18:31:35 INFO]: [NovEcon2] Disabling NovEcon2 v1.0.0
....
[18:31:36 INFO]: [RealBanks2] Enabling RealBanks2 v2.0.0
[18:31:36 ERROR]: [RealBanks2] - Disabled due to no Vault dependency found!
[18:31:36 INFO]: [RealBanks2] Disabling RealBanks2 v2.0.0
```

I have thought about a separate bridge plugin, but afaik, it would end in the same issue, since the bridge-plugin would be needed by NovEcon2, and the bridge-plugin would depend on RealBanks2.

Changing the order of the depended plugins in the `plugin.yml` or adding `loadbefore` didn't help me to come a little closer to a viable solution.

This resulted in nothing but still failing.

Comment: If `NovEcon2` cannot be enabled without `RealBanks2`, why does it `softdepend` on `RealBanks2` instead of `depend`?

Comment: @Lucan Well the `softdepend` is therefore here, since you can enable the `RealBanks2` API in the config, which is disabled by default. If it would be a `depend`, `NovEcon2` would always fail to load (when I don't want to use `RealBanks2` for any reason), even though the `RealBanks2` API hasn't been enabled in the config. as to be shown here: https://codeberg.org/Noveria/NovEcon2/src/branch/kotlin-rewrite/src/main/resources/config.yml#L19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search, the following procedure solved my problem:

There is an event, called `ServiceRegisterEvent`. It can be used to get services, when they are registered on server start.

I listened for the service `Economy` and if that occured, I loaded the Economy-Plugin.

I also had to edit the `plugin.yml` of the Banking-Plugin, to load before the Economy-Plugin.

ServiceRegisterEvent:

```kotlin
internal class ServiceRegisterListener(private val realBanks2: RealBanks) : Listener {
    @EventHandler
    fun onEconomyServiceRegister(e: ServiceRegisterEvent) {
        if(e.provider.service.simpleName.equals("Economy")) {
            if(!realBanks2.setupEconomy()) {
                RealBanks.LOG.severe(String.format("[%s] - Disabled due to no Vault dependency found!", realBanks2.name))
                realBanks2.server.pluginManager.disablePlugin(realBanks2)
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

plugin.yml

```yaml
name: RealBanks2
version: ${project.version}
main: me.linuxsquare.realbanks2.RealBanks
api-version: "1.19"
depend: [Vault, PlayerUUIDCache]
loadbefore:
    - NovEcon2
author: LinuxSquare
website: https://codeberg.org/Noveria/RealBanks2
```